# traveling with no mahram

Tags: women, mahram, travelling

as salaamu alaikum, okay I don’t have a mahram. my father has no Islamic rights over me I was made out of wedlock. my mothers father is non Muslim and I have no brothers nor husband. How do I go about that? I want to do school overseas or even just travel but my mother said I can’t with out a mahram what are the circumstances if you don’t have one? jazakallah khair if you help.

Comment: I don’t understand why there’s a downvote. im just trying to gain knowledge lol